# How to do customer text field validation in angular2 using type script

Tags: javascript, validation, angular, typescript

currently i am learning angular2 with validation part,I am not able to validate simple customer text box field

Here is my HTML Code

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 padding-lft-rght-0">
                        <div class="form-control setup-form margin-btm">
                            <label test_id="lblcustname" class="control-label col-xs-12 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-3" for="">
                                {{ 'CUSTOMER.CNAME' | translate }} <span class="mandatory">*</span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-lg-8 padding-left-0">
                                <input type="text" id="txtName" class="form-control" required maxlength="100" name="CustomerName" [(ngModel)]="customerObj.CustomerName" (ngModelChange)="checkCustomeName($event)" />
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

and below my Typescript code

```
checkCustomeName(event) {

        if (event === "") {
            this.isCustomerNameEmpty = false;
        }
        else {
            var textbox= document.getElementById('txtName');
            if (textbox.nodeValue.length > 100)
            {
                this.isCustomerNameexceed = false;
            }
            this.isCustomerNameexceed = true;


        }
    }
```

So whenever i am debugging using chrome i am not able to get any value in below line..

```
var textbox= document.getElementById('txtName');
```

So is this the correct way to do validation in typescript.

Comment: Is this `angularjs` - Angular v1 or `angular` - Angular v2+?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're only getting the element with

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('txtName');
```

Try

```
var textbox = document.getElementById('txtName').value;
```

Better yet, since you're using databinding, you should be able to use

```
var textbox = customerObj.CustomerName;
if (textbox.length > 100) ...
```

If you want to do the Angular approach, check out form validation [in the angular docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html#!#custom-validation)

Answer (score 0):

First that you have to consider. This template:

```
<input [(ngModel)]="some"/>
```

is same as:

```
<input [ngModel]="some" (ngModelChange)="some = $event">
```

Having

```
<input [(ngModel)]="some" (ngModelChange)="someHandler($event)">
```

is bad idea.

Basically, there is "Angular2 way" for doing validation https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/form-validation.html , but whatever.

Another thing: you do not need reference to `txtField` to get value.

1. `checkCustomeName(event)` - where `event` is your value.
2. If you want to track changes on some scope variable, again do it "Angular2 way" with `ngOnChanges()` lifecycle hook https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/lifecycle-hooks.html